# Prove that a set E is not complete by exhibiting a sequence of points in E that is Cauchy but does not converge to an element of E

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Prove that the set $E=\{(x_1, . . . , x_d) :x_1, . . . , x_d>0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is not complete by exhibiting a sequence of points $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $E$ that is Cauchy but does not converge to an element of $E$.

I know that $E$ is complete if for every sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of points in $E$ that is Cauchy, there exists an $x \in E$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$. So incompleteness would be that there does not an exist such an $x$. I am not sure how to prove this.

Comment: Since $\Bbb R^d$ is complete and $E \subseteq \Bbb R^d$, every Cauchy sequence in $E$ will converge to a point in $\Bbb R^d$.  You just want a sequence within $E$ that is Cauchy but converges to a point outside of $E$.  Can you manage that before looking at the answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{x_n\}$ with $x_n =(1/n , 1/n, \dots,1/n)$.